# Delete Rows if Cell Does not equal to Zero or Blank

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row

I have researched several codes but it's either for blanks only or zeroes only, and I need a code for both blanks and zeroes.

I have 3 columns to note if this should be deleted or not

I need to delete the rows with complete details(ID, and  Address)(the Name is the basis for the details), since I need the rows with incomplete details(ID or Address as zeroes or blanks) to retain.

```
ID        Name        Address        
1         A           123 ABC
2         B           0
          C           345 CDE
          D           
5         E           567 EFG
0         F           678 FGH
7         G           789 GHI
0         H           0
```

My first try was this code, it works for the conditions, but if I have succeeding blanks, it skips the next row, since that row goes up

```
lrow = 1000
For x = 2 To lrow
If Cells(x,2)<>"" Then
If Cells(x,1) <> "" Or Cells(x,1) <> "0" Or Cells(x,3) <> "" Or Cells(x,3) <> "0" Then
Cells(x,11).EntireRow.Delete
End If
End If    
Next x
```

So I tried this code, where I start from bottom to up.

```
lrow = 1000
For x = lrow To 2 Step -1
If Cells(x,2)<>"" Then
If Cells(x,1) <> "" Or Cells(x,1) <> "0" Or Cells(x,3) <> "" Or Cells(x,3) <> "0" Then
Cells(x,11).EntireRow.Delete
End If
End If    
Next x
```

But that code ignores the conditions except the first one, then also deletes the other row s with incomplete details.

I'm kind of stuck with this, since I also have to create another one where I do the reverse, keep the complete details, and delete the incomplete ones.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the for loop with a do while loop. If the row is deleted, decrement the total number of rows, otherwise increment the row counter.

```
lastRow = 1000
row = 2
Do While row <= lastRow
    If Cells(row,1)<>"" Then
        If Cells(row,1) <> "" Or Cells(row,1) <> "0" Or Cells(row,3) <> "" Or Cells(row,3) <> "0" Then
            Rows(row).Delete
            lastRow = lastRow - 1
        else
            row = row + 1
        End If
    End If    
Loop
```

Comment: I tried your code but it still deletes those with blank or zeroes on the code. I edited my trial code above, since the first Condition should be on column 2.

Answer (score 0):

### Delete Rows with Conditions

**Loop Backward**

```
Sub testSimple()
    Const lrow As Long = 1000
    Dim x As Long
    For x = lrow To 2 Step -1
        If Len(Cells(x, 1)) > 0 And Cells(x, 1) <> 0 Then
            If Len(Cells(x, 3)) > 0 And Cells(x, 3) <> 0 Then
                Rows(x).Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

The star of the show is the If statement which should ideally (most efficiently) actually be:

```
If Len(Cells(x, 1)) > 0 Then
    If Cells(x, 1) <> 0 Then
        If Len(Cells(x, 3)) > 0 
            If Cells(x, 3) <> 0 Then
                Rows(x).Delete
            End If 
        End If
    End If
End If
```

All four conditions have to be true. If one isn't, the others are not evaluated.

On the other hand you can write it like this

```
If Len(Cells(x, 1)) > 0 And Cells(x, 1) <> 0 _
        And Len(Cells(x, 3)) > 0 And Cells(x, 3) <> 0 Then
    Rows(x).Delete
End If
```

... the difference being that in the latter (less efficient) all four conditions are evaluated, even if the first is already false.

For the opposite you could use the same conditions and do the following (note the `Else`):

```
If Len(Cells(x, 1)) > 0 And Cells(x, 1) <> 0 _
        And Len(Cells(x, 3)) > 0 And Cells(x, 3) <> 0 Then
    ' Do nothing
Else        
    Rows(x).Delete
End If
```

Let's rewrite the opposite using `Or`:

```
If Len(Cells(x, 1)) = 0 Or Cells(x, 1) = 0 _
        Or Len(Cells(x, 3)) = 0 Or Cells(x, 3) = 0 Then
    Rows(x).Delete
End If
```

So similar to the 'opposite idea' you could write the initial statement like this (note the `Else`):

```
If Len(Cells(x, 1)) = 0 Or Cells(x, 1) = 0 _
        Or Len(Cells(x, 3)) = 0 Or Cells(x, 3) = 0 Then
    ' Do nothing
Else
    Rows(x).Delete
End If
```

**The Finale (for the opposite)**

Using the `Select Case` statement you can write the opposite like this:

```
Sub testSimple()
    Const lrow As Long = 1000
    Dim x As Long
    For x = lrow To 2 Step -1
        Select Case True
        Case Len(Cells(x, 1)) = 0, Cells(x, 1) = 0, _
                Len(Cells(x, 3)) = 0, Cells(x, 3) = 0
            Rows(x).Delete
        End Select
    Next x
End Sub
```

... where the commas 'mean `Or`', so if any of the expressions are true, the rows will be deleted.

**OLD (Continuation):**

**Delete in One Go Using the `CombinedRange` Function**

```
Sub test()
    Const lrow As Long = 1000
    Dim drg As Range
    Dim x As Long
    For x = 2 To lrow
        If Len(Cells(x, 1)) > 0 And Cells(x, 1) <> 0 Then
            If Len(Cells(x, 3)) > 0 And Cells(x, 3) <> 0 Then
                Set drg = CombinedRange(drg, Rows(x))
            End If
        End If
    Next x
    If Not drg Is Nothing Then
        drg.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

**Delete in One Go Using the `CombinedRange` Function Improved**

```
Sub testImp()
    
    Const Cols As String = "A:C"
    Const fRow As Long = 2
    
    Dim rg As Range
    With Columns(Cols).Rows(fRow)
        Set rg = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Set rg = .Resize(rg.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    Dim drg As Range
    Dim rrg As Range
    For Each rrg In rg.Rows
        If Len(rrg.Cells(1)) > 0 And rrg.Cells(1) <> 0 Then
            If Len(rrg.Cells(3)) > 0 And rrg.Cells(3) <> 0 Then
                Set drg = CombinedRange(drg, rrg.EntireRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next rrg
    
    If Not drg Is Nothing Then
        drg.Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

**The `CombinedRange` Function**

```
Function CombinedRange( _
    ByVal BuildRange As Range, _
    ByVal AddRange As Range) _
As Range
    If BuildRange Is Nothing Then
        Set CombinedRange = AddRange
    Else
        Set CombinedRange = Union(BuildRange, AddRange)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand around 50% of this, but I'll still try it out and understand.

Comment: I tried the first code you sent, the one with loop backward, and it works. How do I change it if I'd want the opposite to reflect? Blanks and Zeroes will be deleted, while the rest stay?

Comment: If you consider this solution a ton of `Ands`, then the opposite will be a ton of `Ors` i.e. like you did in your code. Additionally, the conditions have to be opposite:  `If Len(Cells(x, 1)) = 0 Or Cells(x, 1) = 0 Or Len(Cells(x, 3)) = 0 Or Cells(x, 3) = 0 Then`

Comment: I tried it but it only deletes the ones with zeros, and not the blanks.

Comment: Did you put it in one line like in the comment? There is only one `If`.

Comment: Yes, I took out the first If